# Getting a value from HTML format in Bash

Tags: html, bash

I want to verify the status become "ready" before performing the next action.
However, the client return the status in HTML format.
How can I just get the "ready" value?

Code

```
echo "$status"
```

Output:

```
<reply><contents><status>ready</status>
</contents>
<status>OK</status>
</reply>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've got some valid XML there. You can get the `ready` part out like this:

```
xmllint --xpath '//contents/status/text()' file.xml
```

Tempting as it may be in this relatively simple case to use a regular expression to extract the part you're interested in, I would strongly recommend against it, as it is the wrong tool for the job and will break as soon as the input changes slightly. This approach is much more flexible.